# Way to get an MD5 output in Windows like this?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, md5

I am looking for a way to do the following Mac/Linux command on Windows to get the same output. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

cd  ; find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5 -r > ../my_checksums.md5

I understand that certutils can generate an MD5 on a specific file, but is there a way to get it to spit out recursive MD5 with file paths like the above command would do?

Comment: Yes. It can be done in a batch file. See [hashfile for files in define paths using BATCH](//stackoverflow.com/a/55245260) for some inspiration.